# JavaScript substring not working as expected when adding another string

Tags: javascript, string, substring

Can someone help me check this code below and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Expected result

```
'2022-04-02'
```

Output result

```
"02022-04-2"
```

code

```js
const str = '2022-04-2';

console.log(str.substring(8));


console.log(str.replace(str.substring(8, 9), "0" + str.substring(8,9)));
// expected output: "2022-04-02"
```

Answer (score 4):

`replace` with a string target will find and replace the first occurrence of the target. The first occurence of `2` in `2022-04-2` is here:

```
2022-04-2
^
```

and not here:

```
2022-04-2
        ^
```

To do what you want, work with indices, don't use `replace`:

```js
const str = '2022-04-2';

console.log(str.substring(0, 8) + "0" + str.substring(8));
```

Or be more precise about your targetting, if you do use it:

```js
const str = '2022-04-2';

console.log(str.replace(/\b(\d)\b/g, "0$1"))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `replace` doesn't work as you think. In the code you wrote it searches for the first occurrence of the string `"2"` and it replaces it with `"02"`. In your case for `"2022-04-02"` the first `"2"` is the very first character.

I suggest a different approach:

```
const str = "2022-04-2";
const [year, month, day] = str.split("-");
const formattedDate = `${year}-${month.padStart(2, "0")}-${day.padStart(2, "0")}`;
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: what happens if you have your string in this format "2022-04-6 - 2022-04-8", will this method still work @Giorgio Polvara - Gpx

Comment: You will have to split the two dates first `const dates = "2022-04-6 - 2022-04-8".split(" - ")`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by using [string.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

Demo **:**

```js
const str = '2022-04-2';

const splittedStr = str.split('-');

splittedStr[2] = '0' + splittedStr[2]

console.log(splittedStr.join('-'))
```

Comment: _Can someone [...] tell me what I'm doing wrong._